# Can see the json coming back in Developer tools but it's not getting to my $.ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jqplot

I've got a jqplot bar chart and I've attached an onclick event to the bars. When I call the ajax function it all seems to work but I'm not getting any data back. The alert('Success') is firing but ret is still null. I can watch this in Developer Tools and see the json coming back but it's not getting into ret. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $('#chartMonthly').bind('jqplotDataClick', 
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    $('#info1').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
    var ret = null;
    var url = 'wmHours.php';
    var obj = {};
    obj.m = "1";
    obj.d = "4";
    obj.y = '2013';
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: obj,
        dataType:"json",
        success: gotData(ret)
        });  // End ajax

    }); // End function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data), end bind

function gotData(ret){

    alert('Success!');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `success: gotData(ret)` to `success: gotData`.

You only want to provide the callback handler name unless you wrap the call in an anonymous function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#chartMonthly').bind('jqplotDataClick', 
            function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
    $('#info1').html('series: '+seriesIndex+', point: '+pointIndex+', data: '+data);
    //var ret = null;  remove this line as it is useless here
    var url = 'wmHours.php';
    var obj = {};
    obj.m = "1";
    obj.d = "4";
    obj.y = '2013';
    $.ajax({
        //async: false,  you shouldn't do this!!!
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: obj,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(ret){gotData(ret);}
        });  // End ajax

    }); // End function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data), end bind

function gotData(ret){

    alert('Success :'+ret);

}
```

BTW setting  async: false, to any ajax request is really a bad idea!

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I changed removed the async: false as well.